# Jquery Function Only executing of first item

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I wonder if someone can help me out there. Im pretty new to jQuery but loving learning it. I seem to have a slight problem I wonder if someone can help me with. I am using the following jQuery to add userids and property ids to MySQL (like an "add to favourites) The function executes fine on the first property, but not on the other beneath it.

THE JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#clickme").delegate("#insert", "click", function(){

var ruid=$("#ruid").val();
var propid=$("#propid").val();


$.post('inc.saveprop.php', {ruid: ruid, propid: propid},
function(data){
$("#message").html(data);
$("#message").hide();
$("#message").fadeIn(1500); //Fade in the data given by the insert.php file
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

the html: the following is in a loop

```
<? while { 
<input id=\"ruid\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$uid."\" />
<input id=\"propid\"  type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$props['propid']."\" />
<a class=\"insert\" title=\"Insert Data\" href=\"#\">Save to Favourites</a>
 <!-- For displaying a message -->

<div id=\"message\"></div>";
} etc  ?>
```

The script will work for the first item in the loop, but then does not work for the others. 
I know one of the problems is I have multiple hidden types (in the loop) with the same ID's, big no-no but don't know who the change the code to access the id=name+ID or use Class= or Name= instead.

I'd bee really grateful if someone could help me (been googling for hours trying different things and broke it 4 times ha)

Thanks for taking the time to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is that you need to store the two IDs so they can be passed along by the AJAX call to your server.  One way to do this is use jquery's [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) command, which lets you read/write key-value data tied to a specific HTML element.  In this case you can store your two IDs directly in the `<a>...</a>` element.

```
<a class="insert" title="Insert Data" data-ruid="ruid1" data-propid="propid1" href="#">Save to Favourites</a>
```

The other issue you need to solve is how to have an arbitrary number of these 'Save to Favourites' links without having to uniquely name them all.  This is accomplished through the use of classes and the jquery class selector.

**Example HTML:**

```
<div class='clickme'>
    <a class="insert" title="Insert Data" data-ruid="ruid1" data-propid="propid1" href="#">Save to Favourites</a>
    <div class="message"></div>
</div>

<div class='clickme'>
    <a class="insert" title="Insert Data" data-ruid="ruid2" data-propid="propid2" href="#">Save to Favourites</a>
    <div class="message"></div>
</div>

<div class='clickme'>
    <a class="insert" title="Insert Data" data-ruid="ruid3" data-propid="propid3" href="#">Save to Favourites</a>
    <div class="message"></div>
</div>
```

**Example javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickme").delegate(".insert", "click", function(){
        // the 'this' variable refers to whatever was clicked, in this case 
        // it is the <a> ... </a> element with the class 'insert'

        // use the jquery data() command to retrieve the saved IDs         
        var ruid=$(this).data('ruid');
        var propid=$(this).data('propid');

        var data = "ruid: " + ruid + " propid: " +  propid;

        // find the sibling of the <a> ... </a> element that has the class 'message'
        // and update it with the retrieved information
        var message = $(this).siblings(".message");

        message.html(data);
        message.hide();
        message.fadeIn(1500);

        //$.post('inc.saveprop.php', {ruid: ruid, propid: propid}, function(data){
        //    $("#message").html(data);
        //    $("#message").hide();
        //    $("#message").fadeIn(1500); //Fade in the data given by the insert.php file
        //});

        return false;
    });
});
```

jsfiddle of this example: http://jsfiddle.net/wQjhN/7/

Comment: Nice, though if you're going to go HTML5, you might as well use .data() with no args and get the data fields as an object - a little faster than multiple calls, and you don't have to build up the data string to submit (which you lost the submit portion from the OP's code)

Comment: Wow. A very comprehensive answer. I almost cant wait for the morning now to try it. Here's to hoping this is the one!!! Thank you for taking such time to help

Comment: Couldnt wait to try this this morning!. You are a total star!!!! that worked a treat the very first time - I cant thank you enough!!!!!!!!!!! WOW WOW WOW!

Answer (score 2):

You are using an ID in your selector :

```
$("#clickme")
```

ID's are unique and jQuery will only get the first intance of that particular ID, not all of them.

You just need to change your loop a little to use classes:

```
<input class=\"ruid\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$uid."\" />
```

and then use the class in the selector instead:

```
$(".clickme")
```

It's also a good idea to move on to `on()` instead of `delegate()`

```
$("#insert").on("click", ".clickme", function(){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line, fix the HTML generation, and use classes for repeated, similar elements, and IDs for unique elements.

The click handler isn't going to attach to multiple items with the same ID, as it only expects to find one.

You can use @adeneo's fix to address that, but then you'll run into a similar issue with your ruid and propid, and won't be able to read those values properly - you'll again get the first instance of the ruid and propid on the page as you're using IDs and not classes.

While you could come up with some hacky selectors - probably loop on the input elements or something, e.g. `$(this).find('input')` and then loop, assuming the first is the ruid, and the second is the propid.  That's a hack, and fragile at best - if the HTML order changes, everything breaks.

Fix the HTML, and then you'll be able to use proper selectors (probably `$(this).find('.ruid')` or something similar)